# How to use polymer filters in core-list elements

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use a filter for internationalization for a chrome extension

```
i18n:function(string){
    return chrome.i18n.getMessage(string);
}
```

and this is used like this:

```
<paper-tab>{{'SETTINGS'| i18n}}</paper-tab>
```

It works fine except when I am passing a template into a core-list.

```
<core-list id="messagelist" data="{{messageHistory}}">
    <template>
        <div class="msg">{{text}}</div> 
        <div class="type">{{type | i18n }}</div>
    </template
<core-list>
```

I have tried template bind = {{i18n as i18n}}, which did not work. 
It would be nice to know if there is in anything in polymer that would support this. 
Thank you.

Comment: The object that `i18n` function is defined on matters, you didn't specify. Did you put it on `PolymerExperssions.prototype`? That should make it work anywhere.

Comment: I see. This was not in the documentation, so I missed it. [Docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#custom-filters)

Comment: @ScottMiles Is a globally defined filter still the only way to do this? Or did someone update core-list for a more elegant, locally scoped version?

Comment: As of Polymer 0.5, the local filter should work.